# Echo PHP variable in foreach loop

Tags: php

I have my main page set as follows. It has 2 text boxes and a list of checkboxes which is populated from a text file (I'm not using a db as its a simple form). My issue is that I cannot POST the values in the checkboxes and echo them

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        $CN = $Assignee ="";
    ?>

<form action="GPParser1.php" method="post">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>CName:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="CN"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Assignee:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Assignee" ></td>
  <tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Select Vendors:</td>
</tr>
    <td>
      <?php

      $gp = file('GP.txt');

      foreach ($gp as $line_num => $gp)
        {
          //echo '<input type="checkbox" name= $line value=$line>($line)."<br />\n";
        print "
                        <br/>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='" . $gp . "' value='" . $gp . "'>$gp";
        };

      ?>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type="submit">
    </td>


 <?php

 echo $CasinoName;
 echo $Assignee;

 //foreach ($gp as $ln => $gp) {
//  echo $gp;
 //};
?>
</body>
<html>
```

And:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
  <?php

    $CN = $_POST["CN"];
    $Assignee = $_POST["Assignee"];
    $GPS = $_POST ["$gp"];

 echo $CN;
 echo $Assignee;
 foreach ($GPS as $GPss => $GPS)
 {
   echo "$GPS";
 }

 //foreach ($gp as $ln => $gp) {
//  echo $gp;
 //};
?>
</body>
<html>
```

As it is right now I'm getting several errors based around  $GPS = $_POST ["$gp"];

What should I do?

Comment: your $gp variable need to be declared only once you use it on the loop as key->value($gp)  isn't a good pratice, try to limit to rename to a different name.

Comment: At the moment you have checkboxes that have alternating changing `name` values, that mean's there is no way PHP can expect to know what `name` values come in under, which is possible what PHP throwing the error on. Do you want it to be like that or are you trying to send an array of values to PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain if this is the kind of solution you're looking for if I'm wrong, please let me know so I can give a better answer.

My solution is that your form will have a checkbox list that will later become an array of values when the form gets submitted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>
  <?php
        $CN = $Assignee ="";
    ?>

    <form action="GPParser1.php" method="post">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>CName:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="CN"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Assignee:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Assignee"></td>
          <tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Select Vendors:</td>
            </tr>
            <td>
              <?php

      $gp = file('GP.txt');

      foreach ($gp as $line_num => $gp) { ?>
                <p><input type="checkbox" name="gp[]" value="<?php echo $gp; ?>">
                  <?php echo $gp; ?>
                </p>
                <?php }; ?>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <input type="submit">
            </td>
           </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>
  <?php

    $CN = $_POST["CN"];
    $Assignee = $_POST["Assignee"];
    $GPS = $_POST["gp"];

 echo $CN;
 echo $Assignee;
 foreach ($GPS as $GPss => $GPS)
 {
   echo "$GPS";
 }

 //foreach ($gp as $ln => $gp) {
//  echo $gp;
 //};
?>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In both these scripts you are overwriting variables in the foreach loops

```
foreach ($gp as $line_num => $gp)
//                     this  ^^^
//       ^^^ overwrites this
```

and

```
foreach ($GPS as $GPss => $GPS)
//                  this  ^^^
//       ^^^ overwrites this
```

because you are using the same variable name on both sides of the `as`

Instead use another varibale name like this

```
foreach ($gp as $line_num => $gpx)
```

The normal approach is to name the array variable containing the array using a pluralised name like `$items` and the singluar variable witout, like

```
foreach ($gps as $line_num => $gp)
```